# Unable to read data in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, jdbc, azure-databricks

I want to read data from azure sql database in azure databricks through jdbc driver. I am writing notebooks in python. But I am unable to read data:

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2};user={3};password={4}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase, username, password)


df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="dbo.CUSTOMER_HANDLES", column="Bank Name", lowerBo

und=1, upperBound=100000, numPartitions=100)
display(df)
```

It is showing the following error:

```
AnalysisException: 'Partition column type should be numeric, date, or timestamp, but string found.;'
```

Comment: What does `column` do in a `spark.read.jdbc`? Given its name, and the error message, I wonder if it is the partition column the error message is talking about. A column named `Bank Name` sounds like something which is a string type...

Comment: Yes Bank Name is a string . So what else am I supposed to do here?@MarkRotteveel

Comment: I don't know spark, I'm just associating things that may help you find the problem yourself.